# How do pass string into variable using the request api inside my react component?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I can't figure out how to use async calls and promise handling to get my result variable passed

Here's the code I've played around with:

```
import React from 'react';
import {result} from './run.js';



export default class Films extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)

    this.state = { data: 'constructor' }
    console.log('cons')
  }

componentDidMount() {

   this.setState(async (state, props) => { 
        const value = await result;
        console.log(value);

        console.log('didMount')
        return {data:value}
    });

  }

  render (){
    return (
      <div>
       <center> <h1> Weekend Box Office </h1></center>
        <div className = 'data'>
            <h1>{this.state.data}</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I imported my promise object (result) in my component file. I don't know why the string of my promise is not rendering.

Comment: I guess you need to learn first callbacks, promises, async/await and finally react.js. To accomplish what you need, it's necessary call the backend inside the component at componentDidMount and set the state: https://en.reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount 
The reason you are seeing undefined is because you are calling "request(...)" using promises version and the console.log is out of the promise resolve function

Answer (score 0):

you need to use componentDidMount

> componentDidMount is invoked immediately after a component is mounted (inserted into the tree). Initialization that requires DOM nodes should go here

so you need to call your request inside componentDidMount and you need to set result as a state of the component so inside your callback u will call `setState`
to update the result which is the component state

Comment: I've updated the code, as you can see I have implemented my `setState` in the constructor but after the using `await`  in `const value = await result;` I cannot render my `value` variable after that.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, this is what I needed:

```
async componentDidMount() {
  const value = await result;
   this.setState( (state, props) => { 

        return {data:value}
    });
  }
```